# How to get info on Django HTTP 500 error

Tags: python, django, nginx, django-views, uwsgi

I am running a Django 1.8 site on nginx/uWSGI.

On the `./manage.py runserver` everything works as expected, but when I move it to production some views return an HTTP 500 error.

Looking into the uWSGI log I get something like:

```
** View: booking_accept_view 6zN6
[pid: 1959|app: 0|req: 7/7] xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx () {56 vars in 1339 bytes}
[Thu Jun 11 10:00:39 2015] GET /tidsbestilling/admin-accept/6zN6/ =>
generated 27 bytes in 28 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500)
6 headers in 226 bytes (2 switches on core 0)
```

So not much help here.

nginx access log:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [11/Jun/2015:10:00:39 +0200] 
"GET /tidsbestilling/admin-accept/6zN6/ HTTP/1.1" 500 38 
"https://example.com/tidsbestilling/admin-details/6zN6/" 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/600.7.10 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.7 Safari/600.7.10"
```

No entry in nginx error log.

I tried enclosing in a `try-except` block, but I get no information from that.

My view looks like this:

```
def booking_admin_accept_view(request, booking_uid):
    print("** View: booking_accept_view", booking_uid)

    user = request.user
    if not (user is not None and user.is_authenticated() and user.is_active):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('booking_admin_login_view'))

    try:
        booking = Booking.objects.get(uid=booking_uid)
        booking.status = 'accepted'
        booking.save()
        send_sms(booking)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('booking_admin_details_view', args=(booking_uid,)))
    except(Exception, e):
        logging.exception(e)
```

The `booking.save()` is executed, and if I do a `./manage.py shell` I can do the `send_sms(booking)` and that works too, but the view doesn't get that far.

So my question is: how do I get more information on what's going wrong? Do I really have to run in DEBUG mode to get information?

Comment: You mention the uWSGI logs...Have you checked the Nginx logs?

Comment: 500 errors are logged by django. Does it say anything?

Comment: @rnevius: I put the nginx access log entry in the question, but not much help here either.

Comment: Django is capable of notifying you of fatal errors also in production. Have you set the `ADMINS` variable? Please read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/error-reporting/, probably most importantly also the referenced https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-ADMINS

Answer (score 0):

Put the `user = request.user` also in a try-catch block.

Try logging the request to check headers.